# « Cher Monsieur » est-il correct ?

Tags: correspondance, commerce, finance

Récemment, j'ai reçu une réponse formelle d'un organisme financier à une question que je leur ai posée. Cette réponse commençait par cette formulation :

> Cher Monsieur Grégoire,

Ces mots m'ont fait tiquer pour les raisons qui suivent.

- Je pense que « Cher » ne doit être utilisé que dans les lettres familières. Et il devrait être utilisé comme « Cher » suivi de mon prénom.
- Je pense que « Monsieur » devrait être utilisé seul, sans « Cher » et sans mon nom de famille.

Idéalement, si j'étais cette société j'écrirais simplement ceci :

> Monsieur,

Qu'en est-il des recommandations en français à ce sujet ?

Comment: Hmm, «  je serais cette société que j'écrirais simplement ceci » me fait bien plus tiquer que « Cher Monsieur Grégoire » qui est tout à fait acceptable.

Comment: Désolé pour le belgicisme introduit. J'espère ne pas vous avoir froissé. Si vous le voulez, imaginez cela avec un bon accent belge histoire de rigoler et de tiquer moins.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Cher Monsieur Grégoire,

est une formulation commerciale banalisée.
Elle est cependant très familière et dénote un marketing qui me fait mettre la lettre directement à la poubelle.

1. Je n'ai pas été présenté à la personne qui m'envoie cette lettre, et donc je ne peux savoir si je lui suis cher... il s'impose comme familier sans me demander mon avis, uniquement pour fournir une réponse (probablement standardisée).
2. Il n'y a pas de réciprocité, je ne lui ai pas écrit "Cher Monsieur le lecteur de cette lettre qui veut poser une question à votre magnifique Société".
3. Il s'agit d'un problème d'argent et il me fait sentir que je ne suis valorisé que financièrement à ses yeux, je suis *Cher* pécuniairement, pas cordialement, malgré toutes les sucreries qu'il met autour, chose que j'abhorre dans les relations humaines.
4. Je ne vaux pas autre chose à ses yeux que les quelques sous qu'il pourra retirer de notre rencontre, et la façon dont il essayera de me manipuler pour obtenir gain de cause.
5. J'ai un prénom, les gens sensés se définissent par leur nom et prénom, dire François Hollande (sans Monsieur, sauf s'il s'agit de l'annoncer publiquement, auquel cas on ajoutera son titre) pour parler du Président de la République est une marque de respect : il est connu, il est cité dans son humanité, sinon il l'est par sa fonction.
6. Familièrement on pourrait lui répondre : "On n'a pas gardé les vaches (ou, *les cochons*) ensemble".

Votre simple choix :

> Monsieur,

avec un remerciement en fin de lettre pour "... l'attention que vous portez à notre Société..."

est tout à fait bien venu, parfait pour engager un échange épistolaire ou préparer une rencontre hors de tout mercantilisme exacerbé.

Comment: Bien dit!!! Plus familièrement, nous disions chez moi: "On n'a pas gardé les cochons ensemble."

Comment: Quand les mots commencent à être étroitement délimités !

Answer (score 5):

#### Réponse courte

Oui, **« Cher Monsieur/Chère Madame » est correct**, mais tout dépend du contexte, et dans celui proposé par la question, « cher » semble effectivement déplacé.

#### Réponse détaillée

En complément à [la réponse de cl-r](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16940/7224), je dirais que même si le « Cher » semble déplacé ici, « Cher Monsieur » me paraît tout à fait correct (puisque c'est là l'intitulé bref de la question).

Toutefois, comme souligné dans la question et la réponse sus-citée, « Monsieur » (avec la majuscule) traduit une forme de respect, alors que « cher » traduit un attachement (la personne est chère à mon cœur et donc, comme dit dans la question, nous sommes familiers). Les deux ne sont cependant pas exclusifs à mon sens.

Pour exemple, imaginons un professeur auquel vous êtes restés particulièrement attachés, avec qui vous êtes demeurés en contact au-delà de votre cursus d'études, sans pour autant changer la façon dont vous l'appeliez<sup>1</sup>. Si vous échangiez de façon épistolaire, j'imagine parfaitement que votre lettre pourrait débuter par les mots « Cher Monsieur/Chère Madame ».

---

<sub>1. Les enseignants ont une tendance naturelle à rester Monsieur ou Madame Nomdelenseignantici.</sub>

Comment: Pour info, l'intitulé de la question n'est pas la question. Malgré sa forme interrogative, l'intitulé de la question n'est qu'un titre, rendu obligatoire par le logiciel derrière StackExchange, non la question en elle-même. J'aurais pu utiliser "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" comme titre, cela n'aurait rien changé à la question. Mais merci d'y répondre malgré tout.

Comment: @ogregoire Bien que ma réponse ne le laisse pas transparaître, j'en suis tout à fait conscient. L'intitulé peut néanmoins suffire à induire en erreur un lecteur futur trop pressé qui ne prendrait pas le temps de lire le contexte pourtant indispensable que vous avez fourni, raison pour laquelle j'ai souhaité compléter le point de vue de cl-r avec une réponse plus générale.

Answer (score 4):

« Cher Monsieur Grégoire, » est grammaticalement correct.

Si recommandation il y a, elle ne concerne que le savoir vivre.

C'est bien une petite maladresse de cette banque car il est considéré comme impoli d'utiliser le nom de famille du destinataire d'une lettre de cette façon. La place du nom est sur l'enveloppe, pas dans la formule d'appel.

« Cher Monsieur, » n'est normalement utilisé que si l'on connait déjà la personne et que l'on a lié quelque liens, ce qui ne semble pas être le cas ici où « Monsieur, » est donc plus indiqué.

Cela-dit, je pense que la majorité des personnes recevant cette lettre ( contrairement à cl-r **;-)** )  n'accorderaient aucune importance à un « Cher Monsieur Machin, » et ne le remarqueraient probablement même pas. Ce qui les mettrait beaucoup plus en rage serait une mauvaise orthographe de leur patronyme.

Answer (score 1):

"Cher Monsieur," est une formule correcte, mais qui sous-entend une certaine familiarité doublée de respect. Cette formule convient par exemple pour s'adresser à un client avec lequel il y a eu au minimum un contact personnel (par exemple une séance) et pour autant qu'il ait de l'estime pour la personne à laquelle l'on s'adresse. Autrement, cette formule serait hypocrite.

"Monsieur," est de loin la formule la plus courante dans les correspondances formelles de toutes sortes. ("Madame," si l'on s'adresse à une femme.)

Il y a une sorte d'assèchement des relations humaines qui fait que par autocensure, "Cher Monsieur," autrefois courant, tend à se faire rare, étant remplacé par la formule plus neutre et plus sèche "Monsieur,". Personnellement, j'utilise encore "Cher Monsieur," lorsque cela est possible, mais avec circonspection.

"Monsieur Nom_de_famille," est une formule que l'on rencontre de plus en plus en Suisse. Ce n'est clairement pas du bon français et sonne très suisse-allemand (ou anglais). Cette formule vient d'autres langues commme l'allemand où montrer que l'on se souvient du nom de la personne est une marque de politesse: "Sehr geehrter Herr Schmidt, ..."
Une autre raison pour laquelle cette formule est utilisée dans les relations commerciales est que cela "personnalise" la relation.

"Cher Monsieur Nom_de_famille" ne sonne clairement pas français, mais l'on rencontre parfois ce genre de formule pour les mêmes raisons que dans dans le cas précédent.

Quant à Monsieur suivi du prénom, cela fait penser que la personne désignée est un maquereau ou une maquerelle (un homme ou une femme qui débauche et prostitue les femmes dont il/elle tire des revenus).

Answer (score 0):

En Suisse, il est d'usage d'utiliser le Cher Monsieur, Chère Madame un peu partout.

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language SE.  Est-ce que tu peux expliquer pour répondre à la question ?

Comment: Dans des courriers commerciaux? à l'oral?