# Alternative à "Madame/Monsieur" pour commencer une lettre officielle

Tags: correspondance, formulation

Je dois écrire une lettre adressée au Ministère de la Justice française et je ne sais pas qui la lira. Je n'ai donc aucune information sur le nom et/ou le genre de la personne, c'est pourquoi je préfèrerais éviter le "Madame, Monsieur," qui fait omission des autres genres.

Quelle serait une autre manière de commencer une lettre formelle ?

Comment: "qui fait omission des autres genres" Quels autres genres ?

Comment: @Toto Je faisais référence aux personnes de [genre non-binaire](http://www.infotransgenre.be/m/identite/diversite-de-genre/transgenderisme/), aux personnes intersexes qui ne se reconnaissent pas comme étant "seulement" un homme ou aux femmes, bref, à toutes les personnes ne s'identifiant pas comme homme ou femme.

Comment: Dans le cadre d'une lettre administrative, « Madame, Monsieur, » me semble la formule correcte. Voir aussi : https://french.stackexchange.com/q/4539/635 et http://circulaire.legifrance.gouv.fr/pdf/2012/02/cir_34682.pdf . Que je sache, il n'y a pas d'autres circulaires.

Comment: *Madame, Monsieur* semble au contraire assez indiqué comme formule d'appel pour une personne trans-genre...

Comment: Moi à un ministre, j'écrirais... ***"Monsieur, Madame, Mademoiselle** ... sachez qu'en ce moment je suis bien fatigué... j'en ai marre, j'en ai marre, j'en ai marre!"* Et, quelque puisse être son *genre* soit il comprend et apprécie soit... la suite de la lettre ne servirait à rien... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre Vous pensez ? Auriez-vous des sources étayant votre thèse ? J'ai cherché sur Internet, en vain. Mais si cela est vrai, ça résoudrait le problème.

Comment: Je suis la seule source de ce commentaire. Après réflexion, la formule peut être acceptable pour quelqu'un qui se sent à mi-chemin entre les deux, mais pas si la personne ne se considère ni l'un ni l'autre.

Comment: @jlliagre Je prends note. Merci pour le partage de vos réflexions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On pourrait innover et commencer la lettre par,

> Chère personne,

mais la formule d'appel risque de surprendre...

Sinon, il existe une formule toute faite pour s'adresser à une personne inconnue, *à qui de droit*, mais elle est plutôt du registre juridique. La formule d'appel serait alors:

> Qui de droit,

Comment: Qu'est-ce qui pourrait surprendre, la nouveauté du mot personne dans une formule d'appel ou sa combinaison avec « Chère »?

Comment: Une intelligence artificielle pourrait s'en offusquer…

Comment: @LPH L'utilisation du mot *personne*. J'ai ajouté chère car commencer directement par *Personne* est ambigu en français, personne pouvant signifier son contraire, et réciproquement ;-)

Comment: Comme selon ce que je crois comprendre, de toute façon, dans les formules d'appel de lettres de ce type le mot « chère » ne trouve pas beaucoup sa place, il serait tout indiqué de lui fournir un remplaçant. « Personne correspondante, » serait un solution; vous en verriez peut être d'autres…

Comment: @LPH La question de l'utilisation de *chère* me paraît secondaire vis à vis de celle de *personne*...

Comment: Je ne vois pas en quoi l'utilisation de *chère* avant *personne* se doive d'être abandonné. Ça introduit aimablement, ça dispose convenablement, et si la personne en question lit beaucoup de missives, ça ponctue agréablement la journée. La politesse et la courtoisie sont rarement vaines.

Comment: @Montéedelait C'est une question de conventions. On recommande d'éviter *Cher/chère* si on ne connait pas déjà le destinataire.

Comment: Ah bon? Je brise régulièrement (et avec allégresse) les conventions, apparemment.

Comment: @Montéedelait Les avis sur *Cher Monsieur* sont variés, voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/16935/cher-monsieur-est-il-correct

Comment: @jlliagre: *Personne* sans *chère*, c'est incompréhensible. Le caractère anonyme de la formule d'appel change son sens de toute façon. Toute cette discussion est vraiment inutile à mon avis.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Suggerer *Personne* n'était qu'une plaisanterie répondant entre autre à ton commentaire. Je l'ai retirée puisqu'elle était manifestement incomprise.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais entendu parler de cette sorte de formule d'appel multivalente, n'en ai jamais vu l'ombre d'une formule représentative. Il me semble qu'il ne vous reste plus qu'à innover. Comme la personne, ce monsieur, cette dame ou autre à qui la lettre est destinée est un correspondant ou un chargé de correspondance,  pourquoi ne pas vous adresser à ce correspondant en tant que tel; si le service particulier au sein du ministère figure en objet le qualificatif  « de service, » pourrait être ajouté. Si vous n'avez aucun service en tête qui puisse être le juste receveur de votre missive vous pouvez encore ajouter « ministériel ».

- Correspondant,
- Correspondant de service,
- Correspondant ministériel,

D'autres possibilités sur cette base ou une base alternative qu'elle vous suggèrerait  pourraient aussi convenir; l'essentiel est de rester dans les normes d'une bonne logique, il me semble.

Comment: Si j'ai bien compris les inquiétudes d'Avazula, cette formule suppose que le destinataire est un homme, `correspondant` étant mis au masculin, ça ne répond donc pas vraiment à la question. En gros il faudrait trouver un mot invariant en genre

Comment: @Flying_whale Effectivement. Cependant, il est toujours possible d'écrire `correspondant(e)` à la place, et cela résout le problème. J'ai bien conscience qu'on retombe sur les mêmes problématiques qu'avec le `Madame/Monsieur` mais autant il est possible d'éviter de faire mention de genre dans une formule de salutation, autant il me semble impossible de faire de même dans l'accord des noms et adjectifs.

Comment: @Flying_whale Je comprends qu'il veut englober to les titres de civilités (ce qu'il appelle « Madame , Monsieur **et** les autres genres »; il faut, il me semble étendre la couverture en genre des mots existants; une femme qui travaille en tant qu'agent de change reste un agent de change et je trouve cela très bien ainsi (un genre neutre) selon les directives de l'académie, je crois. « correspondant » doit être est un mot neutre.

Comment: @Flying_whale Bien sûr, la possibilité de s'en tenir strictement à la grammaire actuelle et d'ajouter « (e) », comme le suggère Avazula, me semble très bonne, du moins pour le temps présent; mais cela n'a plus beaucoup de sens lorsque l'on considère que le concept d'être asexuel fait déjà beaucoup parler de lui.

Comment: @LPH J'ai du mal à comprendre le lien avec l'asexualité. L'asexualité ne concerne-t-elle pas la faible ou inexistante libido ?

Comment: @avazula Ah oui, ne me laissez pas vous induire en erreur, c'est exactement ce que vous dites. C'est aller trop loin, cela n'implique pas du tout que ces personnes ne puissent pas être médicalement rattachées à un sexe.

Answer (score 1):

Vous pourriez commencer votre lettre de manière neutre en utilisant une salutation telle que "À qui de droit," ou "À l'attention du service concerné," ou "A l'attention du sevice compétant,". Cela permet d'éviter de faire référence à un genre spécifique et convient pour une communication formelle où le destinataire exact n'est pas connu.

A qui de droit est considéré très juridique quand même. Voir [Expression : À qui de droit](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/29439/expression-%c3%80-qui-de-droit).

Answer (score 0):

En théorie, la formule *« Madame, Monsieur »* montre une méconnaissance du destinataire précis, et s'ajoute en conséquence, afin de lui laisser le choix: être Madame, Monsieur, ou tout aussi bien les deux à la fois. Bien entendu, certains se disent chats ou poissons.
Mais je crains que la langue française, autant que la majorité de ses utilisateurs, ait bien du mal à suivre.

*« Madame, Monsieur »*, et bien dans cet ordre (eut égard à la multiplication des féministes) reste donc la tournure la plus sûre dans ce cadre.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Ceci ne répond pas à la question qui demande expressément des alternatives à "Madame, Monsieur".

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives :
"A qui cela concerne,"
"En votre grâce,"
"En votre nom,"

Ceci dit "Madame/Monsieur," ou "Cher/Chère," est tout aussi inclusive quelqu'en soit le genre.

Sinon pour de l'inclusivité des genres:
"À la personne ayant besoin d'asile,"
"À l'agneau perdu,"
"Au cerveau de plume,"

Comment: Mis à part *Madame/Monsieur," ou "Cher/Chère,"* toutes ces propositions ne fonctionnent pas en français,  encore moins pour une lettre officielle comme demandé.